# Dúvidas sobre Forms Authentication ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Tenho um projeto ASP.NET e preciso inserir um controle de usuário para limitar o acesso às páginas. Já existe uma tabela no meu banco com Login e Senha, encontrei alguns tutoriais que explicam como utilizar o *Forms Authentication* mas não entendi muito bem como funciona.

[Eu estava seguindo este tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), mas ele diz "Crie uma pagina ASP.NET chamada Logon.aspx no diretório raiz da aplicação.". Onde seria a minha raiz?

Comment: Eu quero saber como implementar o Form Authentication no meu projeto, estou iniciando agora em asp.net.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx Eu acho que você pode seguir esse tutorial que vc mandará bem.

Comment: Eu estava seguindo este tutorial, mas ele diz "Crie uma pagina ASP.NET chamada Logon.aspx no diretório raiz da aplicação." onde seria a minha raiz? Por que nãoestou  achando a opção de criar novo arquivo em asp

Comment: @ViniciusVAz Por favor, edite sua pergunta com essas dúvidas que responderemos. A seção de comentários não foi feita para "aumentar a pergunta".